# How do states without Voter ID laws ensure that people are who they say they are?

Tags: united-states, voting, law

In the United States, requiring voters to show photo-ID is very controversial. Many claim that it is discriminatory. In states where requiring photo ID is not allowed, how do election officials determine that a person is elligible to vote in that location, and how do they prevent people from voting multiple times?

Comment: The process varies by state and jurisdiction.  In general if you know the name and address under which you are registered that will be enough to get you to the poll if you are in the right polling place.   Which is why in Chicago you can hear things like "Wow Mr Garabini for a 110 year old you don't look a day over 30."

Comment: "[Vote early and vote often](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vote_early_and_vote_often)" - Al Capone.

Comment: Relevant, though not an answer: virtually no cases of fraud could be prevented by voter ID laws: http://www.minnpost.com/politics-policy/2012/08/cases-voter-id-election-fraud-found-virtually-non-existent

Comment: @Avi - But you could eliminate it as a reasonable doubt for officials accused of corruption at the polls.  It is not always reducing an actual problem but sometimes about making it harder to do something unrelated.

Comment: @Chad voting laws exist to ensure fairness in election outcomes. If you pass a law restricting the ability of otherwise eligible voters to vote for no demonstrable benefit, that's a bad law.

Comment: No arguements there... 98% of laws passed since 1900 are bad laws IMO.  But the point of the laws is not to stop voter fraud, the pols dont want that.  they want to appear to be attempting to fight voter fraud.

Answer (score 7):

This varies state by state - but I assume most states without Voter ID laws operate similarly. I will give an example of what I know, NJ.

The answer to "*how do they prevent people from voting multiple times*" is, **"in some places, they don't really do it outside of making you sign a voting roll with the name you are using to vote"**.

E.g. all you need to have is some registered voter's name, easily obtainable via social engineering (find a person's contact info, contact them as if doing a poll, ask if they are registered to vote, ask if they are planning to vote. Things that legit polling firms ask).

---

Specifially, in New Jersey ([src](http://ballotpedia.org/wiki/index.php/State_by_State_Voter_ID_Laws)):

> **If identification was not provided at the time of registering to vote** or if the identification information could not be verified, a voter must show identification at the polling place. Identification includes: any current and valid photo ID or bank statement, car registration, government check or document, etc.

So, there are 2 ways to cheat:

1. Come to vote with fraudulent documents (scan, photoshop, and print a fake bank statement - NOT exactly an impossible task in modern day and age).
2. Come to vote and pretend to be someone who is already registered to vote (as per above, a very easy feat via social engineering).

   As an addendum - when they make you sign in the voter book, you can see and remember any other people's names as they open up pages to find yours, never mind names on your own page. No need even for basic social engineering.
3. **UPDATED** When voting by mail, [the rules are](http://www.longdistancevoter.org/new_jersey#.Um6DcBAmT-A):

   > *Do I need to provide ID when I register to vote?*
   >
   > You must include your New Jersey driver's license number or your non-driver ID number on your voter registration form.  If you don't have either of these numbers, you must include a copy of your ID with your form.  If you forget, you'll need to provide ID the first time you vote in person or by absentee ballot.   Acceptable forms of ID include: a driver's license or other photo identification that shows your name and New Jersey address OR a current utility bill, bank statement, government check, paycheck, or other government document that shows your name and New Jersey address.

   So, you CAN (1) Fail to provide driver's license # when registering and (2) Use an easily forgeable form of ID (a copy of the utility bill and/or bank statement with name and address whiteouted and changed) to then vote by mail without providing harder-to-forge drivers or non-drivers ID.

---

As far as #2, I have definitely observed that you merely state your name at the voting rolls table, **without any effort to certify you are of that name** - even checking your voting invitation letter, and sign the rolls to certify that you voted (so nobody else nor yourself can cast a second vote under that name).

*However, if you know someone else's name **who is already registered to vote**, you can EASILY come and vote a second time as that person. The only four risks are:*

- the super-vigilant 70 year old volunteers supervising the rolls recognize you again.

  (not being sarcastic - anyone else ever have a hyper-vigilant nosy older neighbour? :)

  Can be trivially mitigated; from basic disguise to voting throughout the day to even simpler, voting in different polling places.
- Same volunteers deciding your signature is "wrong"

  Trivially mitigated by using random-scribble signature method, OR "almost same as printed letters" signature method. May not stand later scrutiny if the vote is disputed, but are they ever?
- The person you are impersonating coming to vote earlier and you being arrested for attempted voting fraud

  Can be mitigated by voting as someone you know hasn't voted yet (or coming to vote very early, as per [Al Capone's famous admonition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vote_early_and_vote_often)).

  Or, even better, someone who won't vote at all. Given typical US voting participation rate (shy of 60% [even on high-turnout Presidential elections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_turnout_in_the_United_States_presidential_elections), never mind other lower turnout elections), finding such a person isn't hard.
- The person you are impersonating coming to vote after you voted, and having your vote invalidated.

  Can be mitigated by voting as someone you know won't vote at all. As per above, given typical US voting participation rate (shy of 60% [even on high-turnout Presidential elections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_turnout_in_the_United_States_presidential_elections), never mind other lower turnout elections), finding such a person isn't hard.

  However, given that voting is anonymous, I'm not even sure invalidating your prior vote would be technically possible, so this may not be as much of a concern.

Comment: Wow. So nobody can trust the US elections.

Comment: @Anixx - Not in the states without voter ID laws.

Comment: Those statements are incorrect: the number of cases of fraud that could be prevented by these ID's is virtually zero:

http://www.minnpost.com/politics-policy/2012/08/cases-voter-id-election-fraud-found-virtually-non-existent

Comment: @Avi - let me rephrase that for you a bit - "the number of **alleged, never mind documented proven and prosecuted** cases of fraud"... Which very conventionally excludes what could very well be the bulk of the cases - namely, those nobody knows about since they succeeded. Having peronally witnessed people discussing them, I can assure you they exist. Of course, without a voter ID law, it's absolutely impossible to prove how much fraud actually occurs.

Comment: Rejection of data based on your anecdotal experience does not constitute a valid argument. I recognize this isn't skeptics, but I'm hoping we have a higher standard of evidence here.

Comment: @Avi - claiming that "data" is equivalent to "a small piece of data that was noticed and proven" is not exactly a good argument. There's no process that is actually designed to find voter fraud, so there's no valid data on voter fraud.

Comment: @Avi - There IS however data on people doing illegal things when they can get away with them at no risk (hint: they do it all the time - see Prohibition, drug use, illegal immigration). It's a lot easier to make a sane assumption that people take advantage of being able to commit voter fraud than that nobody does. What my answer proves is that voter fraud is POSSIBLE - AND that the "data" you refer to is absolutely useless to detect that kind of fraud.

Comment: It may be a more valid assumption to assume that people will do illegal things (though I tend to reject assumptions in general), but given data, it is never valid to _assume_ the data are wrong. You'd need to provide contrary evidence or point out expert criticism of the methodology.

Comment: @Avi - My whole answer is the expert criticism of methodology. The statistics is of people who were caught and convited of fraud. I'm showing that given the laws that exist, it's trivial to commit fraud in a way that will NOT get you caught, never mind convicted. In other words, "he number of cases of fraud that could be prevented by these ID's" is "A COMPLETE UNKNOWN and not "zero" as you claimed; but is severely unlikely to be zero based on the ease of committing fraud without risk of being caught.

Comment: I didn't see you referencing any experts on the subject stating that such fraud is common. Considering that I did, I see no reason to think that there is a substantial amount of voter fraud. You're trying to reason your way to something that has to be established empirically.

Comment: @Avi - where in my answer did I say that "such fraud is common"? You referenced a fallacy - your link doesn't prove that such fraud is uncommon, merely that being caught and punished for it isn't common. All I said is that it CAN be common, and there's no proof that it isn't (nor any way to prove that it is or isn't in absence of ID law).

Comment: BTW, you still didn't point out a single specific inaccuracy in my answer (again, the answer does NOT in any place comments on actual proposed amount of fraud, merely on possible mechanisms that none of the audits address). If you notice, the question also didn't ask about fraud magnitude, merely prevention mechanisms.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer, I'm criticizing the statement that nobody can trust US elections (and your agreement with it). Though I do think your answer gives a somewhat different impression than the reality is, even if it's factually accurate.

Comment: @dvk you're arguing a hypothetical--and a rather silly one given that there is also very little motivation to even try and commit in-person voter fraud.

Comment: @DA. - "little motivation"? You seem to be living on a different planet than me then.

Comment: You seem to be implying that voter fraud is a problem because that catching them is a problem. Both are hypothetical and don't mesh with the reality of the fact that committing in-person voter fraud is a quite inefficient way to steal an election. It's arguably (if we're sticking with hypotheticals) not even possible.

Comment: @DA. - where in my answer do I imply that voter fraud is a problem? (as opposed to possibility)?

Comment: @dvk fair point. I can see a difference between problem vs. possible problem, though still find the latter a dangerous tool as it's abused a lot by the talking head pundits.

Comment: @DVK you implied it's a problem when you said agreed that elections in places without voter ID laws can't be trusted. However, there is insufficient fraud preventable by voter ID laws to sway any election.

Comment: @Avi - do you have proof that there's insufficient fraud? (absence of proof that there's fraud doesn't constitute proof that there isn't one).

Comment: Yes, that article I linked in the first comment on this post. Though I might point out that asking me to prove a negative isn't reasonable: if you think there's fraud, the burden of proof is on you to demonstrate that exists.

Comment: @Avi - no, since you're claiming fraud does not exist, the burder on proof is on you. I merely claim that there's no proof EITEHR way, and impossible to obtain one due to the way current voting procedures are. You simply can't prove that Jack Spacey who voted was a real person named Jack Spacey and not someone else - **by design**.

Comment: @Avi - as far as you linking to that article - as I repeatedly noted, I'm not interested in "proof" of absence of something by amount of times people were convicted of that something when the laws are stacked against being caught, never mind convicted. See jaywalking in NYC for another example where this kind of "proof" is false.

Comment: @DVK by saying that the election results are not trustworthy, you are assuming the existence of fraud. And again, the rejection of my data out of hand is not an argument. You need to provide _evidence_, either in the form of expert testimony or an actual study, that the data I've linked to are invalid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11259/discussion-between-dvk-and-avi)

Comment: this answer would be a lot better with out all the added opining about how easy something is to forge or fake.

Answer (score 2):

In Massachusetts, you walk into the polling place and state a name and home address belonging to a registered voter. The poll worker looks at a list and sees if that name and address combination was already used.  If not, they mark it as used, typically with a checkmark, then you go vote.

No ID of any form is requested or accepted at the polling location, nor is any other form of verification.

Answer (score -2):

It’s simple enough.

The Human Element comes into play.

The Poll Volunteers generally have over 20 years of experience.

No Precinct is so large that they don’t know all the roads, streets, and addresses.

If you come in to vote for the first time, you’ll hear them chatter for a moment about EXACTLY where your address is.

Then you’ll need your Voter Registration Card.

Which you only get when you supply sufficient documentation, like a Driver’s license, BC, Social Security Card, utility bills with your name and address, Dog Tags, VA Card, etc.

AFTER that, they know you, greet you by name, and it’s all cool.

Anybody trying to impersonate you is going to get a rude shock when the 70 year old lady at the Ballot table squints and says “You aren’t John Smith, I went to High School with him !”.

The Human Element was how things were done before computers, and it’s a pretty good system with multiple redundancy.

Now, computers could be fooled before facial recognition, and let’s be honest, there’s no Facial Rec or Retinal Scan system in place yet.

I think this is why people mistakenly believe it is easy to get away with Voter Fraud.

They don’t realize that it’s the long-term volunteers that are the watchdogs.

Now, suppose somebody DID bus in migrants or vagrants.

Nobody knows them, so they have to go through the process.

If they claim to be “John Smith” and they’re not, they go to jail.

If they lie and claim they just moved to the Precinct, they’re going to need to Register.

Some States have same-day Registration but many don’t.

They’re going to need to show proof of their address; you have to live IN the Precinct to vote there.

The logjam that would be created by anybody attempting this on Election Day would shut down voting entirely, and it would attract suspicion.

You have to see the voting process as an assembly line.   Any attempt to tamper with the process WILL get noticed as the line breaks down.

To ensure this doesn’t happen, we have Poll Watchers, from both major Parties.

And they can Challenge anybody they think doesn’t belong in the Precinct.

With the Poll Volunteers as the first line of defense, and the Poll Watchers as the second line of defense... anybody trying this would fall flat on their face.

James O’Keefe and his merry band of lying hoaxers tried to prove Voter Fraud was possible in the 2012 Republican Primary.

Seven of them took names from the Obits.

They went in claiming to be “John Smith” and tried to get Ballots.

Even in the lower-pressure environment of a Primary, two of them got caught and had to run before the cops got there.

Now, this is SIMPLE.

If 2 in 7 attempts at Fraud got caught, and you needed a million successful attempts to swing an Election, what will the Headlines in the newspaper be the following day?

MASSIVE ATTEMPT AT VOTER FRAUD FOILED, PARTY LEADERS IN JAIL.

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote this for good points, or downvote it for the formatting and lack of anything to support it.  +0 for now.

Comment: It is pretty rare to actually catch them though.  The reason that a few get caught is because it is so easy to get away with a few get sloppy.  There are districts where the population is very migrant.  But the fraud is happening at a local scale to affect boards and regional positions more than national elections.

Comment: "you'll need your voter registration card" is simply the most easily disproven falsehood of the many in this answer